# 70s to 90s sci-fi book: team goes to a planet, they all die except a giant

Tags: story-identification, books

SciFi book, late 70s to early 90s. Team is assembled. They go to a planet. There is a large person/giant in the group. Nobody survives except the big guy. The cover, I seem to remember, had a large person pushing a boulder à la Sisyphus.

Comment: Please add some more details, such as plot points, character features, etc. Also, check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory. Good luck.

Comment: Why did they go to said planet? For exploration? Or to fix some sort of catastrophe?

Comment: Was it a government or an individual who assembled the team?  How many were there?  How far away was the planet?  If it was a hard-sci-fi book, how did they get there?

Comment: I think one of the short stories in 'Anthonology' by Piers Anthony has something like this as its storyline - big guy who is generally treated by his colleagues as being a bit dumb purely because of his size, but he is the sole survivor of the survey team which is wiped out by local fauna

Answer (score 8):

There's not much to go on but my first thought was [*Under a Calculating Star*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?187973) (1975) by John Morressy.

As I recall, the book starts with a team trying to find some legendary treasure and being killed off one by one by a series of elaborate booby traps. I think there were two survivors, the giant and the main protagonist.

The 1975 doubleday edition (see link) shows a figure supporting a large boulder (or small planetoid perhaps):

[image: brown, minimalist illustration of a man shouldering a boulder]